# Valid docker-compose file not deploying as stack when using yaml anchors

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have been refactoring some docker-compose files to try and take advantage of [tip #82](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-82-using-yaml-anchors-and-x-properties-in-docker-compose) and hit a problem I haven't been able to find a solution to; I'm hoping someone can assist.

Using the following stripped example `test-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

x-test: &test
  deploy:
    mode: replicated

services:
  hello-world:
    <<: *test
    image: alpine
    command: ["ping", "www.google.com"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

Running under `docker-compose` works as expected:

```
root@docker01:~# docker-compose -f test-compose.yml up
Recreating root_hello-world_1 ... done
Recreating root_hello-world_2 ... done
Attaching to root_hello-world_2, root_hello-world_1
hello-world_1  | PING www.google.com (172.217.16.228): 56 data bytes
hello-world_1  | 64 bytes from 172.217.16.228: seq=0 ttl=114 time=6.704 ms
hello-world_2  | PING www.google.com (172.217.16.228): 56 data bytes
hello-world_2  | 64 bytes from 172.217.16.228: seq=0 ttl=114 time=6.595 ms
```

However launching the same as a stack, fails:

```
root@docker01:~# docker stack deploy --compose-file test-compose.yml hello-world
(root) Additional property x-test is not allowed
```

Is there a way to get the same extensions ("x-* properties) working for both docker-compose and stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, two things are going to bite you here:

First, docker stack deploy is fussy about the version you specify, so you need to strictly specify a valid compose version equal to or higher than the feature you are trying to use. Not sure when anchor support was added, but it definitely works when the version is specified as "3.9".

Your next problem is that merging is shallow. In your example case this isn't a problem because `x-test` contains only one setting which is already on its default value, but more generally, to handle complex cases, something like this is needed:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
x-defaults:
  service: &service-defaults
    deploy: &deploy-defaults
      placement:
        constraints:
        - node.role==worker

services:
  hello-world:
    <<: *service-defaults
    image: alpine
    deploy:
      <<: *deploy-defaults
      replicas: 2
```

As adding "deploy" to the hello-world map completely overrides any entry set by the default-service, it needs its own anchor reference to import sub-settings.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you! I thought '3' would suffice. I've updated locally and it's not throwing an error any more. Also noted about shallow merging and I'll update my prod instance with that too.

Comment: Extension fields on root level are supported since '3.7'. Version '3' equals to '3.0'.